# Install CodeTogether-Plugin in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I want to install the CodeTogether-plugin for Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition but somehow it doesn't work.
In Visual Studio, I click Extensions->Manage Extensions->Online->Visual Studio Marketplace
If I know search for "Code Together", nothing is found.
I have found the installation guide here: https://www.codetogether.com/docs/codetogether-for-vs-code-installation/
I have also tried to download the vsix-file, but double-clicking it is of no use.
Is it simply impossible to install CodeTogether for Visual Studio and just for VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned extension if for Visual Studio Code (VS Code). VS Code is a completely different product from Visual Studio (VS) and so are the extensions. Extensions for VS Code don't work with VS and vice versa.